# Ajax call's not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
var quoteUrl='http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=json';
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $loader = $("#btn"),
      $insertion=$("#insertionPoint");
  $loader.click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url:quoteUrl ,
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(data){
        var quote=data.quoteText;
        $insertion.replaceWith('<p>'+quote+'</p>');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Random quote Machine</h1>

<div id="insertionPoint">
  <p>Quotes come here</p>
</div>
<button id="btn">Next Quote</button>
```

Task:To gain a quote from forimastic.com's Api

Result:  Nothing is Happening

Additional:How can I add codes to  make it to gain random quotes if this works?

Comment: try `$($loader).click`

Comment: $($loader).click(function() {......});       No not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by using jsonp and its callback, following the [manual](http://forismatic.com/en/api/) from the API's website.

And I even made it prettier :D

```js
var quoteUrl='http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&jsonp=parseQuote&lang=en';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url:quoteUrl ,
      crossDomain: true,
      jsonpCallback: 'parseQuote',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success:function(data){
        $("#insertionPoint>#quote").html(data.quoteText);
        $("#insertionPoint>#author").html(data.quoteAuthor);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<h1>Random quote Machine</h1>

<blockquote id="insertionPoint">
  <span id="quote">Quotes come here</span>
  <footer id="author">Author comes here</footer>
</blockquote>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="btn">Next Quote</button>
```

You should change `#insertionPoint`'s html instead of replacing it, otherwise the function will no further work since this element will no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
   $insertion.replaceWith('<p>'+quote+'</p>');
```

with

```
 $insertion.html('<p>' + quote + '</p>');
```

Comment: The json call is not working as well, cross-domain problems, perhaps only in stack overflow.